# after updating the state, component is called twice in react-redux, which leads to getting initial state again instead of updated state

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here onShowFriends is my click event to handle the set status flag to true, if this is true I want to show the  component, I'm setting to true in Friends Reducer... Which is firing and I'm able to set the flag after setting the flag component is again reloading and the state is again setting back to initial state how can I solve this problem I'm new to react and redux
https://github.com/kumar155/ReactRedux-Issue1

This is my reducer:

```
var initialState = {
     status: false,
     friends: [
    { id: 1, name: 'satish', status: true },
    { id: 2, name: 'satish1', status: true },
    { id: 3, name: 'satish2', status: true },
    { id: 4, name: 'satish3', status: true },
    { id: 5, name: 'satish4', status: true }]

  }
 export const FriendsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case Types.ADD_FRIEND:
                return Object.assign({}, state, { friends: addFriend(state.friends, action) });
            case Types.GET_LIST:
                return Object.assign({},state,state.status = action.isShow);
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    export default FriendsReducer;
```

Component:

```
     export class Add_A_Friend extends Component {
            constructor(state) {
                super();
                this.props = state;
            }

            render() {
                let Fname, Fcity;
                return (
                    <div className="container">
                        <form className="form-signin">
                            <br /> <br /> <br />
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Friend Name" ref={x => Fname = x} />
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="City Name" ref={x => Fcity = x} />
                            <br />
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{ marginRight: 10 }} onClick={() => this.props.onAddFriend(Fname, Fcity)}>Add Friend</button>

                            <button className="btn btn-warning" style={{ float: 'right' }} onClick={() => this.props.onClear()}>Clear</button>

                            <button className="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.props.onCheck(Fname)}>Check Name's</button>

                            <button className="btn btn-success" style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} onClick={() => this.props.onShowFriends(true)}>Show My Friends List</button>

                            {this.props.state.FriendsReducer.status && <Friends_List />}

                        </form>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        Add_A_Friend.PropTypes = {
            onAddFriend: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            onClear: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            onCheck: PropTypes.func.isRequired
        }

        const mapPropsToState = (state) => {
            return {
                state: state
            }
        };

        export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
            return {
                onAddFriend: (Fname, Fcity) => {
                    dispatch(AddFriend(Fname.value, Fcity.value));
                },
                onClear: () => {
                    dispatch(ClearFriend());
                },
                onCheck: () => {
                    dispatch({ type: Types.CHECK_FRINDS });
                },
                onShowFriends: (isShow) => {
                    return dispatch({ type: Types.GET_LIST, isShow });
                }
            }
        };
        function AddFriend(name, city) {
            return {
                type: Types.ADD_FRIEND,
                name, city
            }
        }
        function ClearFriend() {
            return { type: Types.CLEAR }
        }

        Add_A_Friend = connect(mapPropsToState, mapDispatchToProps)(Add_A_Friend);

        export default Add_A_Friend;
```

Comment: you don't need to do `this.props = state;` in constructor. The `state` is already mapped to props by the `connect`. So just remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I removed and tried still the same result..

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDeafult is not a function and the result will be same page still reloading

Comment: check my answer, it was a typo. it is `e.preventDefault`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if the page is reloading then seems like when clicking on button your form is being submitted. you need to add this to prevent it

```
onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.props.onShowFriends(true)}}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDeafult is not a function, still page is reloading

Comment: should be `e.preventDefault` not `e.preventDeafult`